# Change datatype of column to integer (column with n/a) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a column (phase_mapped) in PostgreSQL 11.0 with integers and n/a values. Current datatype of the column in nchar(3). I would like to convert the datatype of this column to integer but n/a is throwing an error. How can I set int datatype of such columns.

```
phase   phase_mapped
Phase 1   1  
Phase 2   2  
n/a       n/a
```

I tried following query

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ALTER COLUMN phase_mapped TYPE INT USING phase_mapped::integer;
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an expression in the `using` part that deals with the `n/a`. You probably need to deal with empty strings as well.

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ALTER COLUMN phase_mapped TYPE INT 
  USING nullif(trim(nullif(phase_mapped,'n/a')),'')::integer;
```

Or simply remove all non-digit characters:

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ALTER COLUMN phase_mapped TYPE INT 
  USING nullif(regexp_replace(phase_mapped,'[^0-9]', '', 'g'),'')::integer;
```